# Joomla File Handling - Variable name not passed

Tags: joomla, components

I made a component with a "file" field type, but the content of that single field are not passed at all, I was under the impression it should save the file name as text at least, if I change the field type to "text" the name saves so I know everything else is functioning. All the other fields are being passed. What am I doing wrong?

File handling aside, I just want it to save the name.

A detailed explanation would be appreciated, or even better, can I get someone who knows what he's doing re-write this component using MVC so I can compare.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't really help with what you have so far as you haven't provided any code, however our website have recently made a small simple component for Joomla 2.5 for file uploading using the SWFUpload framework, should you want to use it.

http://joomjunk.co.uk/products/component-home/swfupload.html